# Utilisation of Large Datasets in Neo4J

Tags: java, neo4j, garbage-collection, cypher, heap-memory

I have recently been testing the capabilities of Neo4J for large datasets and have begun to run into issues.

Firstly, both the ingestion time (csv->neo4j) and query time seem excessive for even the smallest datasets. For example, a 1GB dataset takes around 50 minutes to convert, and simple -[:RELATION*1..2]- queries take several minutes; this running on a sever with 160 cores and 4TB of ram.

From initial analysis this seems to be some sort of garbage collection problem, but varies heap metrics (young generation etc.) only seems to affect this ingestion time by +/- 10 minutes (a reasonable reduction, but still seemingly high). Has anyone else experienced a similar situation/has a solution, or is this a known problem?

Secondly, the datasets vary from 1.2GB - 10GB in there CSV format, but scale up at a factor of about 7 (1.2GB becomes 7.6GB) when in neo4j. Is this to be expected, or does it seem rather excessive

Additionally, I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and neo4j version 2.3

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Are you using `LOAD CSV` for import or the `neo4j-import` tool? Can you share the Cypher queries that you are having performance issues with?

Comment: if you suspect GC problems then posting GC logs would be helpful. enable `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, was away from my computer over the weekend. I am using LOAD CSV on fairly generic commits, the largest of which has just over a million entities. I am just going to run with the GC log enabled, will post here after.

Comment: I dumped the log onto pastebin as it is rather long (http://pastebin.com/raw/LzyMXr86). I am going to try individual queries and the importer to see if the times differ and shall post the findings.